# Android:How to run code depending on simultaneous hard key press?

Tags: android, onkeypress

I am trying to implement a functionality when i press the VOLUME DOWN and POWER BUTTON simultaneously; i must be able to run a method code inside my Activity.

```
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
 {
  }
```

From my initial search; it seems that only one such key press event is acknowledged at a time in Android usng the onKeyUp method. Is it true?

In my Android phone, on simultaneously pressing POWER BUTTON as well as MENU BUTTON i am able to capture a screen shot.

Does this feature not acknowledge simultaneous key presses?

Answer (score 1):

I've not looked into this before, and don't have an environment on this computer to test, but is there not a "onKeyDown"?

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN ) {
        _volumeDown = true;
        testCombo();
        return true;
    } else if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
        _powerButton = true;
        testCombo();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN ) {
        _volumeDown = false;
        return true;
    } else if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER ) {
        _powerButton = false;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
private void testCombo() {
    if ( _powerButton && _volumeDown ) {
        // Do what Ever
    }
}
```

Again code is untested but the logic I think should be correct...

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your attention. I tried this above code but it does not facilitate acknowledgement of simultaneous button clicks. When i pressed both at the same time; it is either _powerButton or _volumeDown that ends up being true. Never both. Can you please confirm.

Comment: So it does not fire both onKeyDown events? What happens if you press each button slower? EG: Press vol down, see that it triggers _volumeDown = true, wait 1 second, press power button while volume down is pressed, see if it triggers _powerButton = true. I wouldn't have thought it would cause onKeyUp of VolDown when Power button is pressed.. Sadly I again am at the computer with no environment to test.

Comment: Hi W, i tried as you suggested and it does not give _powerButton = true when i keep the volume down pressed and then press the power button. I am using a Samsung gts 7582. Any suggestions?

Comment: Clearly simultaneous perception of button clicks does seem to be possible in case of screen shot using this device. Any pointers as to how that action is possible?